# error management when parsing multiple floats

Tags: parsing, error-handling, http, go, floating-point

I am writing a handler to render a GIF of a Lorentz attractor. I need to parse floating point numbers from the some querystrings attached to the GIF path. If any of them are bad, I need to log an error.

```
func lorenzHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var e error
    rho := atof(r.FormValue("r"), &e)
    sigma := atof(r.FormValue("s"), &e)
    b := atof(r.FormValue("b"), &e)
    if e != nil {
        log.Printf("bad parameters: r=%s; s=%s; b=%s;\n", r.FormValue("r"), r.FormValue("s"), r.FormValue("b"))
    } else {
        // draw lorenz GIF with parameters rho, sigma and b
        // but until then...
        log.Println("yay!", rho, sigma, b)
    }
}


func atof(s string, e *error) float32 {
    if *e == nil {
        var x float64
        x, *e = strconv.ParseFloat(s, 32)
        return float32(x)
    }
    return 0
}
```

Is passing around an error, then cleaning it up, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I miss the reason you are working with a pointer of an error and passing it in different functions.

Why not doing in the simple way?

```
func lorenzHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    rho, e1 := strconv.ParseFloat(r.FormValue("r"), 32)
    sigma, e2 := strconv.ParseFloat(r.FormValue("s"), 32)
    b, e3 := strconv.ParseFloat(r.FormValue("b"), 32)
    if e1 != nil || e2 != nil || e3 != nil {
        log.Printf("bad parameters: r=%s; s=%s; b=%s;\n", r.FormValue("r"), r.FormValue("s"), r.FormValue("b"))
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    // draw lorenz GIF with parameters rho, sigma and b
    // but until then...
    log.Println("yay!", rho, sigma, b)
}
```

If the problem is about performance, and you want to stop after the first error, without waiting all three executions, you can do

```
func lorenzHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    rho, err := strconv.ParseFloat(r.FormValue("r"), 32)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("bad parameters: r=%s\n", r.FormValue("r"))
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    sigma, err := strconv.ParseFloat(r.FormValue("s"), 32)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("bad parameters: s=%s\n", r.FormValue("s"))
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    b, err := strconv.ParseFloat(r.FormValue("b"), 32)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("bad parameters: b=%s\n", r.FormValue("b"))
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    // draw lorenz GIF with parameters rho, sigma and b
    // but until then...
    log.Println("yay!", rho, sigma, b)
}
```

Comment: I heard the idea, but had not seen the doc, that [errors are values](https://blog.golang.org/errors-are-values). I was trying to see if this was an application. After looking at your solution and the doc I am not quite sure what the right approach is. I am not saying I think your approach goes against what the document is advising. Just the combination of your answer and the document leaves me confused.

Comment: What leaves you confused?
Sure, errors are values, and for the language you can do what you did, but using the same variable for three different calls, passing it with a pointer is a lack of readability and is error-prone (in a very simple functions like this).

I think the most idiomatic way to do it in Go is my second example.
* "Return early" handling all bad cases and then work with standard case in a non-nested body *
I understand it's a bit verbose, so I prefer my first example (when I can merge some error handling together).

Comment: Thanks. I usually use C where `f(..., &r)` is not confusing for return. But here when multiple return values are available, persisting a single tiny object makes no sense.